# Find n natural number such that the volume around x-axis is $\frac{14\pi}{15}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

$f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\cos(n\arccos(x))$

I need to find $n$ natural number such that the volume I get around x-axis is $\frac{14\pi}{15}$

The right answer is $n=2$

I started with the notation $t=arccosx$ and I got $V=\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{2}(nt)\cdot \sin(t)dt$

How to continue ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the trig identities
$$
2\cos^2\theta = 1+\cos(2\theta)
$$
and 
$$
2\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi) = \sin(\phi-\theta)+\sin(\phi+\theta)
$$
to write the integrand as a sum of sine functions. The integration should be easy from there.